# How can send "AA68030100000000000000001655" Hex with serial.write()? Python

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

i want send `self.raw = "AA68030100000000000000001655"` this frame like a `{AA}{68}...{55}` with serial.write.

When I execute

```
bus.write(self.raw[0]).encode('utf-8')
```

sends `{41}`

If use

```
bus.write((self.raw[0]+self.raw[1]).encode('utf-8'))
```

sends `{41}{41}`

How I can send `{AA}`?

Thanks

Comment: 41h is the hexadecimal code for ASCII 'A'.  You are sending an ASCII representation of a string of hexadecimal digits. Your requirements are ambiguous, since "hexadecimal" is a radix, not an encoding.  It seems that you don't want to send an ASCII hex encoding, but rather the binary integer value represented by the hexadecimal?

Answer (score 1):

Convert each pair of ASCII characters representing a byte in hexadecimal to an integer value and send the integer byte value.

41h is the hexadecimal code for ASCII 'A'.
You cannot "send hexadecimal"; hexadecimal is a radix, not an encoding.  You either want to send a binary sequence represented by the hexadecimal string, or the ASCII representation of the binary data as hex digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to import codecs and use them like:

```
bus.write(codecs.decode(self.raw,'hex_codec'))
```

This sends the info as I want.

Comment: I think this is the same as:
`bus.write(bytes.fromhex(self.raw))`

Comment: Is better than my solution! With your code i don't need import codecs.
Thanks!